# Permissible to ask for translations of Latin place names?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Is it permissible to ask for an English (or other) translation of a Latin place name?

Comment: I'm not a moderator here but in my opinion it certainly is!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

Translating place names from Latin to other languages is certainly permissible.
And so is translating place names from other languages to Latin, although it is not always reasonably possible.